# How to definitively access a private method within a class?

Tags: typescript

Consider this standard TypeScript class and a private method:

```
class foo {
    private doThis() {
       ///
    }
}
```

Inside the class, one would use the following to access a private method:

```
this.doThis();
```

Unless, it's in a closure/event, in which case we cache the class reference:

```
const classRef: any = this;
$('#foo').on('click', function() {
    classRef.doThis();   
});
```

Of course, the approach breaks down if you are several layers of "this" down and you need to get to the top level of the class.

So, is there a definitive method of accessing class level private methods (or class level variables)?

Comment: When does `this` inside a class _not_ point to the class instance? You need to provide more code to demonstrate this.

Comment: @sdgluck I did.  Inside the `click` handler for the `#foo`, `this` refers to the element, not the class.

Comment: You say " the approach breaks down several layers of "this" down" - what about your solution in the `click` handler does not work for "several layers of "this" down"?

Comment: @sdgluck I fired up a quick codepen that demonstrates the problem.  Open up the console to see the output of `this`.  https://codepen.io/FrankRizzo/pen/MWwbbzQ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use an arrow function inside a closure:

```
class foo {
    private doThis() {
       ///
    }

    otherFunction() {
        $('#foo').on('click', () => {
            this.doThis();   
        });
    }
}
```

your this will always be the class ref.